# Adding tabs in top and bottom of the activity simoultaneously in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

### I am having a `SherlockActionbar` with `Tab` Using `view-Pager`

---

**Current Output**:: (Clearly you can see three tabs on top)

[image]

---

**My Code**::

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    ViewPager mPager;
    Tab tab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Activate Fragment Manager
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Capture ViewPager page swipes
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                // Find the ViewPager Position
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        };

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
        // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
        ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
        // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
        mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

        // Capture tab button clicks
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

        // Create first Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create second Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create third Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {

            // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;

            // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;

            // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

---

**How can i achieve this Or is this possible**::(*I need three tabs at top and three tabs at bottom*)

[image]

**If this is possible what changes should i need to make for my code ?**

Comment: What's stopping you from using a normal `TabHost` for the bottom tabs?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right you want to have the same tabs in top and bottom simultaneously both tied to the contents in between?

If so, I would suggest extending tabhost activity from sherlock library and change the layout so that the tabs are in both in top and bottom using the same variable.

Hope this helps.